# Pivoting input data - is there a structure I can use?

Tags: c#, data-structures, tabular

I have input data given as a list of objects:

```
Name: "Room A",
Time: "15:00",
Topic: "Some Topic"

Name: "Room A",
Time: "18:00",
Topic: "Some Other Topic"

Name: "Room B",
Time: "12:00",
Topic: "Some More Topic"

Name: "Room C",
Time: "13:00",
Topic: "Even More Topic"
```

and I have to create different tables from that. For a start, there should be a table where rows are based on time, and cols are based on the Name, but in the future, when the objects grow, I would like to be able to pivot around other properties.

I would like to code something like the following:

```
var structure = new SomeCSharpStructure(); // <------

for(int i=0;i<24) structure.AddRow(i+":00");

foreach(var name in inputData.Select(x=>x.Name).Distinct()) structure.AddColumn(name);

foreach(var data in inputData) {
    structure[data.Name][data.Time] = data.Topic; // or
    // structure.AddCell(data.Name,data.Time,data.Topic);
}

...

foreach(var row in structure.getRows()) foreach(var cell in row.getCell())
{
     PrintCellContent(cell);
}
```

although I am also open for other suggestions.

But right now I am searching for a structure that would support such an instantiation without spilling `NullPointerExceptions` or `IndexOutOfRangeExceptions` all over the place. Before I implement it myself, I'd like to make sure there is none available.

Does anyone know a structure that would suit my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing custom code that groups your data, you can use [NReco.PivotData](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NReco.PivotData/) library that already implements pivot table calculations (I'm the author of this library, and it can be used for free). It provides PivotTable structure for accessing table values in terms of rows and columns:

```
var pvtData = new PivotData(new[] {"Name", "Time"}, new CountAggregatorFactory() );
pvtData.ProcessData( inputData, new ObjectMember().GetValue );
var pvtTbl = new PivotTable(new[] {"Name"}, new[] {"Time"}, pvtData);
var columns = pvtTbl.ColumnKeys;
var rows = pvtTbl.RowKeys;
var cellValue = pvtTbl[0,0].Value; // get first cell value
```

Some explanations:

- PivotData class build in-memory cube (multidimensional dataset) and performs data aggregation
- ObjectMember provides POCO-model property accessor for dimension values
- PivotTable class provides table model that may be used for pivot table rendering. It can be used for getting totals and subtotals.

Comment: Too late for me, but hopefully this helps other users. :-)

Comment: @Alexander well, now you know about PivotData for the next time :-)

Comment: @VitaliyFedorchenko: do you think your library can solve my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43991726/c-sharp-how-to-pivot-multi-level-data-over-multiple-columns?noredirect=1#comment75012455_43991726 I am pulling data from cube and adding data into List<List<string>>. Any help suggestion is greatly appreciated

Comment: @OpenStack yes you can use PivotData for pivoting your data. I've provided an answer with sample code snippet in your question.